# How to assign dataframe to array R

Tags: r, arrays, loops, dataframe

I have an array I am trying to iterate through, but when I try to assign to it and I get to the second 3rd dimension, I'm thrown an error.

```
  dataSetsTrain <- array(NA,dim=c(nrecords,ncol(set),numFolds))

  for(k in 1:numFolds)
  {
    objTrain <-set[folds!=k,]
    objTest <- set[folds==k,]

    dataSetsTrain[,,k] = objTrain
    #same/similar error
    #dataSetsTrain[,,k] -> objTrain
  }
```

Error

```
Error in dataSetsTrain[, , k] <- objTrain : 
  incorrect number of subscripts
> dataSetsTrain[,,k]
Error in dataSetsTrain[, , k] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: is nrecords == sum(length(folds==k)) ?

Comment: nrecords is nrow(set)

Comment: yeah then each element of your array has nrow = nrecords . you need to do array(NA,dim=c(nrecords/numFolds,ncol(set),numFolds))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `simplify2array()` with the help of splitting the matrix by a factor. Using the `iris` dataset:

```
simplify2array(lapply(split(iris[, -5], iris[5]), as.matrix))
```

And a smaller subset:

```
DF <- iris
lst <- split(iris[, -5], iris[5])

simplify2array(lapply(lst, function(x) as.matrix(x[1:5, ])))

, , setosa

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2

, , versicolor

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4
2          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5
3          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5
4          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3
5          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5

, , virginica

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5
2          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9
3          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1
4          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8
5          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2
```